# Ubuntu Bash Script dialog menu issue with coding an interactive Calendar and delete option

Tags: bash, user-interface, dialog

The below is the code I am trying to run. Essentially it is a dialog bash script that allows the user to click on various options ranging from date/time to system information. The issue is that my calendar and delete file options are not working when running it on Ubuntu. The file browser for the delete option does not appear despite having tried to code it with a gui based input. Also, I do not know if it is an issue with my code but the "ok" and "cancel" buttons in the dialog menu do not appear to be working and I have to constantly run the script again to select a different option. Could someone maybe give an insight as to what the problem might be. Thank you

```
#!/bin/bash

# create an empty events file if it doesn't already exist

touch events.txt

while true; 
do

    OPTION=$(dialog --menu "Select an option:" 0 0 0 \

        1 "Save event" \

        2 "Retrieve event" \

        3 "Show events" \

        4 "Date/Time" \

        5 "Calendar" \

        6 "System Information" \

        7 "CPU Information" \

        8 "File Mounted" \

        9 "Delete File" \

        10 "Folder Delete"\

        11 "Memory Information" \

        12 "Hard Disk Information" \

        13 "Exit" \

        3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- )


if [ $OPTION -eq 1 ]; then

        dialog --clear --msgbox "$(date)" 0 0

elif [ $OPTION -eq 2 ]; then

        DATE=$(dialog --clear --calendar "Select a date:" 0 0 2>&1 1>&2)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

            # check if there's an event for the selected date

        EVENT=$(grep "$DATE" events.txt | cut -d ':' -f 2)

if [ -z "$EVENT" ]; then

                # prompt for new event

        EVENT=$(dialog --clear --inputbox "Enter event:" 0 0 2>&1 1>&2)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

         echo "$DATE:$EVENT" >> events.txt

                fi

            else

            dialog --clear --msgbox "Event on $DATE: $EVENT" 0 0

            fi

        fi

elif [ $OPTION -eq 3 ]; then

dialog --clear --msgbox "$(cat events.txt )" 0 0

elif [ $OPTION -eq 4 ]; then

dialog --clear --msgbox "$(date)" 0 0

elif [ $OPTION -eq 5 ]; then

dialog --clear --calendar "Select a date:" 0 0

elif [ $OPTION -eq 6 ]; then

dialog --clear --msgbox "$(uname -a)" 0 0

elif [ $OPTION -eq 7 ]; then

dialog --clear --msgbox "$(lscpu)" 0 0

elif [ $OPTION -eq 8 ]; then

dialog --clear --msgbox "$(mount)" 0 0

elif [ $OPTION -eq 9 ]; then

path=$(dialog --clear --inputbox "Enter the path of the folder containing the file you want to delete:" 0 0 2>&1 1>&2)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

if [ -d "$path" ]; then

cd "$path" || exit

file=$(dialog --clear --inputbox "Enter the name of the file you want to delete:" 0 0 2>&1 1>&2)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

if [ -f "$file" ]; then

rm "$file"

dialog --clear --msgbox "File $file deleted successfully" 0 0

else

dialog --clear --msgbox "File $file not found" 0 0

fi

fi

else

dialog --clear --msgbox "Folder not found" 0 0

fi

fi

elif [ $OPTION -eq 10 ]; then

path=$(dialog --clear --inputbox "Enter the path of the folder containing the folder you want to delete:" 0 0 2>&1 1>&2)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

if [ -d "$path" ]; then

cd "$path" || exit

folder=$(dialog --clear --inputbox "Enter the name of the folder you want to delete:" 0 0 2>&1 1>&2)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

if [ -d "$folder" ]; then

rm -r "$folder"

dialog --clear --msgbox "Folder $folder deleted successfully" 0 0

else

dialog --clear --msgbox "Folder $folder not found" 0 0

fi

fi

else

dialog --clear --msgbox "Folder not found" 0 0

fi

fi

elif [ $OPTION -eq 11 ]; then

dialog --clear --msgbox "$(free -m)" 0 0

elif [ $OPTION -eq 12 ]; then

dialog --clear --msgbox "$(df -h)" 0 0

elif [ $OPTION -eq 13 ]; then

break

fi


done
```

So the calendar option should give the user the ability to save, retrieve and show events and fault of it not working, i tried to code these options separately rather than under the calendar options and same thing was done for the delete option which was initially coded such that it only displays a box asking for the file name to delete whereas this should be a gui based input where a popup is displayed and lists all files, folders and directories on my pc and subsequently gives the option to delete, cancel the process with a message appearing after or print a message saying file/folder does not exist.

Comment: Better give output example. Also check the format of your file. For example, your file might not be using standard spaces, and also possibly using CRLF.

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Okay thank you all, i'll try to work on the format.

Comment: If you start by writing the code logic in pseudo-code, fine-grained for each task that you are trying to accomplish, in the correct sequence and in the correct context, then having that worded so that it does exactly what you want it to do will, almost explicitly, tell you WHAT you need to code for each of those, not the HOW. The HOW is the nitty gritty of coding. What you have outlined above in your question does not demonstrate that level of detail on the task breakdown. If you give that a try, the solution will almost pop out of the page at you. Good luck with your apprenticeship!